# react native : how to append two object arrays

Tags: arrays, react-native

i have some array of objects inside this.state.messagestable like this

`[{"message_id":"186", "message":"this is some message"},{"message_id":"185", "message":"i love bacon"},{"message_id":"184", "message":"music is magic"}]`

I have fetched message from my websocket into an array variable called feed_msg which looks like this

`[{"message_id":"187", "message":"becareful what u wish for"}]`

How do i add the message from feed_msg to this.state.messagestable to get it to render in my component. A little reminder that feed_msg is not a state array

here is what i've already tried

`this.setState({ messagestable: [...this.state.messagestable, feed_msg] })`

i want this.state.messagestable to finally look like this but im getting no changes in this.state.messagestable

```
 [{"message_id":"187", "message":"becareful what u wish for"},{"message_id":"186", "message":"this is some message"},{"message_id":"185", "message":"i love bacon"},{"message_id":"184", "message":"music is magic"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways, including `concat`, `unshift` and correctly used `...`

```js
const a = [{"message_id":"186", "message":"this is some message"},{"message_id":"185", "message":"i love bacon"},{"message_id":"184", "message":"music is magic"}];

const b = [{"message_id":"187", "message":"becareful what u wish for"}];

// option 1
console.log(b.concat(a));
// option 2
console.log([...b, ...a]);
// option 3
a.unshift(...b)
console.log(a);
```

Comment: option 1 appends the two arrays but how do i assign the final data to this.state.messagestable. Console.log this.state.messagestable still gives the origianal dataa